# Structural directive - ngTemplateContextGuard not working

Tags: angular, type-inference, ngtemplateoutlet, angular-structural-directive, template-context

I've built a datatable compoonent where I'm using a structural directive to pass a rowTemplate:

```
<bs-datatable [data]="artists">
  <tr *bsRowTemplate="let artist">
    <td class="text-nowrap">{{ artist.name }}</td>
    <td class="text-nowrap">{{ artist.yearStarted }}</td>
    <td class="text-nowrap">{{ artist.yearQuit }}</td>
  </tr>
</bs-datatable>
```

I'm trying to provide type inference in my custom structural directive, so the generic type of the structural directive should be infered from the parent component. [According to the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#improving-template-type-checking-for-custom-directives), you should be able to simply implement a `ngTemplateContextGuard`:

```
@Component({ ... })
export class DatatableComponent<TData> {
  @Input() data: TData[] = [];
}

@Directive({ selector: '[appDatatableRow]' })
export class DatatableRowDirective<TData> {
  constructor(public datatable: DatatableComponent<TData>, public template: TemplateRef<TData>) { }

  static ngTemplateContextGuard<TData>(dir: DatatableRowDirective<TData>, ctx: unknown)
    : ctx is DatatableRowContext<TData> {
      return true;
    }
}
```

The type inference on the component works as expected:

[image: Angular component type inference]

But I can't get the structural directive to infer this generic type:

[image: Angular directive inside component type inference]

The goal is obviously to have the `$implicit` variable inferred in VS Code:

[image: ng-bootstrap datatable type-inference not working]

Why is this not working as I would expect? What am I still missing? I want the structural directive to infer the generic type of the parent datatable.

- The minimal reproduction is [hosted here](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/infertest)
- The entire project with the actual datatable is [hosted here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/advanced/datatables)
- The project is already full of similar examples: [`InstanceOf`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/instance-of/src/directives/instanceof-case.directive.ts#L34-L39) - [`Let`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/let/directive/let.directive.ts#L42-L44) - [`Select2`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/select2/src/directive/item-template/item-template.directive.ts#L14-L16) (similar problem)

Similar articles/discussions:

- [Type-safe MatCellDef](https://nartc.me/blog/typed-mat-cell-def/)
- [Angular Material Table - Strong typing of cell templates](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/22290) with other similar linked issues

Comment: Solved. Solution incoming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `of` notation of structural directives:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[bsRowTemplate]' })
export class BsRowTemplateDirective<TData> {

  constructor(private datatableComponent: BsDatatableComponent<TData>, templateRef: TemplateRef<BsRowTemplateContext<TData>>) {
    this.datatableComponent.rowTemplate = templateRef;
  }

  @Input() set bsRowTemplateOf(value: PaginationResponse<TData> | undefined) {
    this.datatableComponent.data = value;
  }
  
  public static ngTemplateContextGuard<TData>(
    dir: BsRowTemplateDirective<TData>,
    ctx: any
  ): ctx is BsRowTemplateContext<Exclude<TData, false | 0 | '' | null | undefined>> {
    return true;
  }
}

export class BsRowTemplateContext<TData = unknown> {
  public $implicit: TData = null!;
}
```

Datatable

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bs-datatable',
  ...
})
export class BsDatatableComponent<TData> {
  ...

  rowTemplate?: TemplateRef<BsRowTemplateContext<TData>>;
  data?: PaginationResponse<TData>;
}
```

Usage

```
<bs-datatable #tabel [(settings)]="settings" (settingsChange)="loadArtists()">
  <div *bsDatatableColumn="'Name'; sortable: true">
    1. Artist
  </div>
  <div *bsDatatableColumn="'YearStarted'; sortable: true">
    2. Year started
  </div>
  <div *bsDatatableColumn="'YearQuit'; sortable: true">
    3. Year quit
  </div>

  <tr *bsRowTemplate="let artist of artists">
    <td class="text-nowrap">{{ artist.name }}</td>
    <td class="text-nowrap">{{ artist.yearStarted }}</td>
    <td class="text-nowrap">{{ artist.yearQuit }}</td>
  </tr>
</bs-datatable>
```